# AWS Step Functions standard workflows concurrent executions limit

Tags: aws-step-functions, aws-service-quotas

I am looking for a concurrent execution limit for *AWS Step Function Standard Workflows.* In AWS docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/limits-overview.html Express workflow concurrent execution limit is mentioned but the Standard Workflow concurrent execution limit is not mentioned.

Can someone help me with this, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preceding quota seems to apply:

> Maximum open executions per account: 1,000,000 executions per AWS Region. Exceeding this will cause an ExecutionLimitExceeded error. Does not apply to Express Workflows.